# How to correctly describe the type of the residual parameter (the rest parameter) using array combining?

Tags: typescript

Example code:

```
function func1(...args: string[] | number[]) {
    //...
}
```

Error text:

```
error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
```

I do not need the following code, because I will have an array of strings 
or an array of numbers, but not an intersection - an array of numbers or lines.

```
function func1(...args: (string | number)[]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: So wait, what's your question?

Comment: `|` is actually union, not intersection.

Answer (score 2):

There's an issue for that: [Using a union type for a rest parameter type annotation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5077) which is closed as "By Design".

What you can do (and it is stated there) is:

```
function func1(...args: number[]);
function func1(...args: string[]);
function func1(...args: any[]) {
    //...
}
```